# Selection of records in RPGLE subfile program

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a rather interesting problem at hand. There is a subfile program that displays certain Manufacturing order records and details stored in a file(say FILEA). The program uses RPG operations to read and display the data in the file.

A new requirement has come up to filter out the displayed MOs based on some criteria. The criteria is not straightforward and does not depend on direct field values of FILEA. Rather it depends on a complex set of rules that needs some calculations.

Now, there is another program(say PGMLOGIC) which filters out MOs based on these rules and puts them in an outfile.

What I have in mind is to come up with some sort of mechanism where I can utilise this existing program PGMLOGIC and to obtain the required MOs in the outfile as it usually does. Once this outfile is created with the required records, I want to make the subfile RPG to display only those MOs in the outfile created by PGMLOGIC and FILEA.

I know that this can be done by modifying the subfile program to do a condition check to see if the MO in FILEA is present in the outfile as well before displaying.

However I am interested to know as this is a matter of record selection, can this done in some other way like OPNQRYF etc?

The sequence of steps then would be:

1) Call PGMLOGIC to create outfile.
2) Do an override on FILEA to select only those MOs which are present in the outfile.
3) Call the subfile program.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: I'd say definitely maybe you can do it another way. More a more definitive answer, we will need explicit examples. What does the outfile look like? What does FILEA look like? Are you able to make modifications to PGMLOGIC to maybe put the data processing portion into a service program?

Comment: Don't use OPNQRYF.  Embedded SQL is more powerful, easier to read, and blessedly free of OVRDBF scoping issues.

Comment: Yes records can be filtered in any number of ways. In fact, you might even be able to load your subfile from the outfile, or join FILEA and the outfile in SQL. Or even with straight RPG. Unfortunately, I can't give you a good answer as there are only vague concepts in your question.

Comment: why not loading all MOs in the outfile, calling the PGMLOGIC pgm which removes unwanted entries, returning to the main programm which reads all records from the subfile, chaining on the outfile. If there is not "match" make a DELETE on the subfile

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies. I do have a solid plan in mind which I think is suitable for this scenario. So the plan is to call the program which creates the outfile with the required mos. join it with FILEA to create a new temporary outfile. Override FILEA to the new temp file. Call the sub file program. This will now display only the required mos.

Answer (score 0):

I think for what you are doing, it may look cleaner and be easier to understand if you instead make the program an SQLRPGLE and do an inner join between FILEA and the created outfile. Just a thought though, what you are planning on doing should work.